# iPhone SDK 3.1?

Tags: iphone

I downloaded iPhone SDK 3.1 with Xcode 3.2 for Snow Leopard from Apple, but when I go to install it, it says it's installing iPhone SDK 3.0.

How can I find iPhone SDK 3.1?  I can't get any apps on my phone until I upgrade my SDK because my iPhone is on 3.1.

In the Organizer it says the OS installed on my phone is 3.1 (7C114) and the XCode supported iPhone OS versions are 3.0 (7A341) and the older ones.

I've downloaded the package from Apple twice now, but both times the package only indicates it is installing iPhone 3.0.

Is there a way to find the 3.1SDK separately?

Thank you,

Elisabeth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the 3.1 sdk from the [iphone apple developer connection](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action)

The xcode 3.2 download DOES NOT include the iphone 3.1 sdk

Comment: So, when I go to that page, I see, under Snow Leopard downloads:
iPhone SDK 3.1 with Xcode 3.2 (Snow Leopard)

That's that one I've been downloading that only installs 3.0.

I do not see a separate download for iPhone SDK 3.1.

Do I need to sign up for a separate program to get it? What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured it out. In the install package it lists the 3.1SDK only as "iphone SDK". Since I already have 3.0 and 2.1 installed, I'm deselecting those and installing only the 3.1SDK.